# VideoJS IMA Setup

Tags: video.js

I'm trying to follow the GettingStarted instructions on https://github.com/googleads/videojs-ima to setup videojs with ima. But, am getting stuck on the part "In player.js, load the ads library"; nothing has been changed in the local player.js file so it still looks exactly the same as here https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/src/js/player.js.

Bellow is the current code I have, but when it's ran in IE11, the console reports a warning and two errors:

1. Warning: "VIDEOJS: WARN: videojs.plugin() is deprecated; use videojs.registerPlugin() instead" in video.js (489,5)
2. Error: "SCRIPT1002: Syntax error" in player.js (5,1)
3. Error: "CSS3120: No fonts available for @font-face rule" in video-js.css (12,7)

Any input very much appreciated.

Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Load dependent stylesheets. -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/6.2.0/video-js.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-contrib-ads/5.0.2/videojs.ads.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-ima/0.6.0/videojs.ima.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <video id="content_video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
                controls preload="auto" width="440" height="260">
            <source src="//vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
        <!-- Load dependent scripts -->
        <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/6.2.0/video.js"></script>
        <script src="//imasdk.googleapis.com/js/sdkloader/ima3.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-contrib-ads/5.0.2/videojs.ads.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-ima/0.6.0/videojs.ima.js"></script>
        <script src="src/js/player.js"></script>
        <script>
            var player = videojs('content_video');

            var options = {
              id: 'content_video',
              adTagUrl: 'https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?sz=640x480&iu=/124319096/external/single_ad_samples&ciu_szs=440x260&impl=s&gdfp_req=1&env=vp&output=vast&unviewed_position_start=1&cust_params=deployment%3Ddevsite%26sample_ct%3Dlinear&correlator='
            };

            // This must be called before player.play() below.
            player.ima(options);
            player.ima.requestAds();
            // On mobile devices, you must call initializeAdDisplayContainer as the result
            // of a user action (e.g. button click). If you do not make this call, the SDK
            // will make it for you, but not as the result of a user action. For more info
            // see our examples, all of which are set up to work on mobile devices.
            // player.ima.initializeAdDisplayContainer();

            // This must be called after player.ima(...) above.
            player.play();      
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The first warning was fixed in [master](https://rawgit.com/googleads/videojs-ima/master/src/videojs.ima.js) branch via [this PR](https://github.com/googleads/videojs-ima/pull/382)

Comment: did you every figure this out?